# Disable Using Bright Colors for Bold Font in gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

gnome-terminal uses bright colors for bold fonts. Is it possible to configure it to use the same color for bold fonts as for normal fonts. Also, I do need bright colors somewhere else, so changing the color palette probably wouldn't help.

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

GNOME Terminal version 3.28 added a brand new configuration option for this, called “Show bold text in bright colors”, as seen at the bottom of the screenshot. Disabling this option results in what you're looking for. That is, when any of the first 8 palette colors is combined with the “bold” property (SGR 1 escape sequence), it doesn't affect the color (as opposed to when that option is enabled, in that case the counterpart from the next 8 are used. The remaining colors are never brightened).

You should also disable “Bold color” in the same dialog. This one matters when the “bold” (SGR 1) property is applied to the *default* foreground color.

(Note that these options have been disabled by default for a few years now in GNOME Terminal, that is, new users get the behavior you were asking for. Users upgrading from older versions might still need to alter these in the preferences.)

[image: Show bold text in bright colors]

Answer (score 0):

Open your gnome-terminal and open the "Profile Preferences": `Edit -> Profile Preferences`

Go to the `Colors` tab and select the `Same as text color` checkbox on the `Text Color` option.

Take a look at my screenshot showing the "Profile Preferences" dialog:

[image: Gnome Terminal Profile Preferences]

Comment: I don't think this is right; this seems to cause bold text without any color information to use the same color as non-bold text without color info, but colored bold text still seems to go for the bright colors.

Comment: I don't have a testing env. to that, but setting the bold color and the normal color as similar colors would solve that issue?

Comment: It would, but the reason people are wanting this is (I suspect) because they want to use a terminal color scheme that uses both normal and bright colors (eg, solarized).