# Disable Using Bright Colors for Bold Font in gnome-terminal 3.22.x?

Tags: gnome-terminal

This question was answered (5 years ago) for an earlier version where the profile/colors had an check box for making bold colors the same as text.  No longer the case in  version 3.22.x of gnome-terminal.  Since there are already escape sequences to specifically print bright/light colors, it would be great if bold and bright were orthogonal attributes.

Answer (score 0):

“it would be great if bold and bright were orthogonal attributes” – You are absolutely right here!

GNOME Terminal 3.28 introduces this new behavior as a configuration option (although it's not the default yet – UPDATE it's been the default for quite a while now). See https://superuser.com/a/1301425.